# Directly load spacy model from packaged tar.gz file

Tags: python, model, nlp, load, spacy

Is it possible to load a packaged spacy model (i.e. `foo.tar.gz`) directly from the tar file instead of installing it beforehand? I would imagine something like:

```
import spacy 

nlp = spacy.load(/some/path/foo.tar.gz)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, that's currently not possible. The main purpose of the `.tar.gz` archives is to make them easy to install via `pip install`. However, you can always extract the model data from the archive, and then load it in from a path – [see here for more details](https://spacy.io/usage/models#download-manual).

```
nlp = spacy.load('/path/to/en_core_web_md')
```

Using the [`spacy link` command](https://spacy.io/api/cli#link) you can also create "shortcut links" for your models, i.e. symlinks that let you load in models using a custom name instead of the full path or package name. This is especially useful if you're working with large models and multiple environments (and don't want to install the data in each of them).

```
python -m spacy link /path/to/model_data cool_model
```

The above shortcut link would then let you load your model like this:

```
nlp = spacy.load('cool_model')
```

Alternatively, if you *really* need to load models from an archive, you could always write a simple wrapper  for `spacy.load` that takes the file, extracts the contents, reads the [model meta](https://spacy.io/api/top-level#util.get_model_meta), gets the path to the data directory and then calls [`spacy.util.load_model_from_path`](https://spacy.io/api/top-level#util.load_model_from_path) on it and returns the `nlp` object.

Comment: I did `python -m spacy link ...` and it says I can load using `spacy.load('cool_model')`. But when I try to load it complains that no `__init__.py` is found at `venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/data/cool_model/`

Answer (score 2):

Its not the direct answer but it might be helpful in order to load compressed models directly with `SpaCy`. This can be done by using `pickle`.

First, you need to load your `SpaCy` Model and dump it compressed with `pickle`:

```
import spacy
import pickle

s = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", parse=False)

pickle.dump(s, open("save.p", "wb"))
```

Afterwards, you can load easily somewhere else the pickle dump directly as `SpaCy` model:

```
s = pickle.load(open("save.p", "rb"))
```

Comment: Bless you my friend