# Loading a spacy .tar.gz model artifact from s3 Sagemaker

Tags: model, spacy, amazon-sagemaker, artifact, tar.gz

I have a pretrained spacy model on a local folder that I can easily read with `m = spacy.load("path/model/")`

But now I have to upload it as a .tar.gz file to use as a Sagemaker model artifact.
How can I read this .tar.gz file?

Ideally I want to read the unzipped folder from memory. Without extracting all to disk and then reading it again

My question is almost a duplicate of this one [Directly load spacy model from packaged tar.gz file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49274650/directly-load-spacy-model-from-packaged-tar-gz-file). But the answers don't explain how to untar unzip the folder into memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Sagemaker already decompress the `.tar.gz` file automatically.
So I can just read the folder exactly like before.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [serialization docs](https://spacy.io/usage/saving-loading/). You don't want to read the unzipped folder from memory (I'm not sure how that would work exactly), but you can use simple in-memory serialization, for example. In that case you save the config and the model separately.

To save:

```
config = nlp.config
bytes_data = nlp.to_bytes()
```

To read back:

```
lang_cls = spacy.util.get_lang_class(config["nlp"]["lang"])
nlp = lang_cls.from_config(config)
nlp.from_bytes(bytes_data)
```